# Upper diagonal of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

This seems simple (and is trivial to write a three-line loop for), but how can I use numpy slicing make a list of the index locations of the upper diagonal of a numpy array? I.e.

Given a 4x4 array, I'd like the index locations at the X's:

```
[ X X X X ]
[ 0 X X X ]
[ 0 0 X X ]
[ 0 0 0 X ]
```

Giving:

```
[ (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3) ]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

carnieri beat me to the `numpy.triu_indices` answer, but there is also `numpy.triu_indices_from` which takes an array as input rather than the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (Justin and Carnieri). Two things to note, this needs numpy 1.4 which is currently not the standard on Ubuntu. Also one can get the requested indices by simply unziping the answer, ie. `zip(*numpy.triu_indices(X))`.

Answer (score 7):

Though the format of index locations is different, it seems like you want the function [`numpy.triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html).

Answer (score 2):

[`scipy.linalg.triu`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.triu.html) and [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Ubuntu and don't want to upgrade Numpy just for this, you can use the following function:

```
from itertools import chain
triu_indices = lambda x, y=0: zip(*list(chain(*[[(i, j) for j in range(i + y, x)] for i in range(x - y)])))
```

Example:

```
In [26]: triu_indices = lambda x, y=0: zip(*list(chain(*[[(i, j) for j in range(i + y, x)] for i in range(x - y)])))

In [27]: triu_indices(4)
Out[27]: [(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3)]

In [28]: zip(*triu_indices(4))
Out[28]: 
[(0, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 3)]
```